# API Documentation using XML Comments in SwaggerHub

Tags: xml-comments, swaggerhub, rspec-api-documentation

I am trying to update API documentation for REST APIs.

Currently, I have a C# Asp.net Web API code and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.
I am editing and adding XML comments in C# using Visual Studio to update the API documentation.

Is there a way I can do this using SwaggerHub or some other tool that lets me use Markdown.

I have not found any solutions for this online.

Answer (score 0):

The SwaggerHub editor supports comments with Markdown syntax for text formatting.

I would suggest checking out SwaggerHubs documentation on Comments for more information. https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/collaboration/comments.html